# Control the order of buttons to select from

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I control the order of the button selection on a project I'm currently working on.

The project has a couple of buttons on gesture detection and I'm wondering if there is a way to let the user select a certain button before the other. Is the Navigation Class helpful in this case? All the buttons are on the same page. THANK YOU!

EDIT: This is the code

```
enum Talba {
  Bab,
  Sita,
  Saba,
  Thimanya,
  Bawan,
}

enum Shary {
  Lina,
  Lihum,
}

enum Score {
  Win,
  Lose,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Talba selectedTalba;
  Shary selectedShary;
  Score selectedScore;

  int Bab5 = 5;
  int Sita6= 6;
  int Saba7 = 7;
  int Thimanya8 = 8;
  int Bawan9 = 9;

  String output = '0';

  var Lina;
  var Lihum;

  var Win;
  var Lose;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AlNashra'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        print(Lihum);
                        selectedShary = Shary.Lihum;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedShary == Shary.Lihum
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(
                      label: 'lihum',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        print(Lina);
                        selectedShary = Shary.Lina;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedShary == Shary.Lina
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'lina'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReusableCard(
                        color: kInactiveCardColor,
                        cardChild: CardChild(
                          label: output,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReusableCard(
                        color: kInactiveCardColor,
                        cardChild: CardChild(label: output),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      Bawan9 = Bawan9;
                      setState(() {
                        print(Bawan9);
                        selectedTalba = Talba.Bawan;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedTalba == Talba.Bawan
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(
                      label: 'Bawan',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      Thimanya8 = Thimanya8;
                      setState(() {
                        print(Thimanya8);
                        selectedTalba = Talba.Thimanya;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedTalba == Talba.Thimanya
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'Thimanya'),
                  ),
                ),
                 Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      Saba7 = Saba7;
                      setState(() {
                        print(Saba7);
                        selectedTalba = Talba.Saba;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedTalba == Talba.Saba
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'Saba'),
                  ),
                ),
                 Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      Sita6 = Sita6;
                      setState(() {
                        print(Sita6);
                        selectedTalba = Talba.Sita;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedTalba == Talba.Sita
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'Sita'),
                  ),
                ),
                 Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      Bab5 = Bab5;
                      setState(() {
                        print(Bab5);
                        selectedTalba = Talba.Bab;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedTalba == Talba.Bab
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'Bab'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        print(Lose);
                        selectedScore = Score.Lose;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedScore == Score.Lose
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(
                      label: 'lose',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        print(Win);
                        selectedScore = Score.Win;
                      });
                    },
                    color: selectedScore == Score.Win
                        ? kActiveCardColor
                        : kInactiveCardColor,
                    cardChild: CardChild(label: 'win!'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
            ],

          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show code what have you done

Comment: Depending on your code, your last resort is state variables.

Comment: Please share your current code so that we can help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hey @Dev updated.

Comment: @diogomelo code updated

Comment: Is what you are trying to achieve a sort of staggered approach, where some buttons are only visible, or enabled, after the user pressed the previous button?

Comment: @JoãoSoares No, the way we have right now is a bunch of buttons (each enum represents a category of buttons), and if one is selected that button will be highlighted. We want the users to select an option of each enum, but cannot select an option from another enum category unless they select an option from the enum prior to it. Hope that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @joaoSoares buttons to be enabled!